# In-app-billing on android (purchase confirmation, json string)

Tags: android, json, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm having problems with coding payments.

This is a web game and here's how I would like the payments to work.

You got to a site and click a button(buy). You are redirected to a site that will send the information of a purchase to the server adding the bought item to your account. Before that happens we have a WebViewClient that checks all the urls. If he find an url that is meant for purchases he will send the purchase request. Now if we will get a message back from android market that it was successful he will proceed with the redirect.

I'm quite new to this and just can't grasp the concept of these payments. I wrote my code using the dungeon example. I tried to adjust it to my needs. I would be grateful is someone could point me in the right direction. Atm I'm trying to figure out how to get the response of a successful purchase. Assuming that the rest of my code is ok it should be working (I hope).

I have in my project files BillingReciver.java, BillingSerivce.java, PurchaseObserver.java, ResponseHandler.java, Consts.java and Security.java that were in the example. If need be I can provice the code of these but there is a lot of it, so I'm hoping someone who already seen the example will be able to help.

---

After some research and consulting with some people I found what I need:

```
     /**
     * This is called when Android Market sends information about a purchase state
     * change. The signedData parameter is a plaintext JSON string that is
     * signed by the server with the developer's private key. The signature
     * for the signed data is passed in the signature parameter.
     * @param context the context
     * @param signedData the (unencrypted) JSON string
     * @param signature the signature for the signedData
     */
    private void purchaseStateChanged(Context context, String signedData, String signature) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Consts.ACTION_PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED);
        intent.setClass(context, BillingService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNED_DATA, signedData);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNATURE, signature);
        context.startService(intent);
       }
```

I need to get the data out of the JSON string that my app will get from android market. Anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: how do I get a response from the android market that the purchase request was successful?

Comment: Have you defined the public key of your develper account? (somewhere in the Security.java class, if you are using the Android developers official sample) Without it you will not be able to confirm any purchase.

Answer (score 2):

On Nov 17 '11 at 21:56 @Grzegorz 'Gatz' Siennicki wrote:

> I need to get the data out of the JSON string that my app will get
>   from android market. Anyone have an idea how to do that?

Look at the `verifyPurchase()` method in `Security.java` module in the sample:

```
JSONObject jElement = jTransactionsArray.getJSONObject(i);
int response = jElement.getInt("purchaseState");
PurchaseState purchaseState = PurchaseState.valueOf(response);
String productId = jElement.getString("productId");
String packageName = jElement.getString("packageName");
long purchaseTime = jElement.getLong("purchaseTime");
String orderId = jElement.optString("orderId", "");
String notifyId = null;
if (jElement.has("notificationId")) {
  notifyId = jElement.getString("notificationId");
}
String developerPayload = jElement.optString("developerPayload", null);
```

Note that since the JSON is generated by the Android Market, those const-strings that specify the field names in the `JSONObject.getXXX()` methods are "hard coded" (i.e. you can't really name them anything you want).

Answer (score 0):

From the android documentation on In App Billing:

> ...when the requested transaction changes state (for example, the purchase is successfully charged to a credit card or the user cancels the purchase), the Android Market application sends an IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast intent. This message contains a notification ID, which you can use to retrieve the transaction details for the REQUEST_PURCHASE request.

Got that from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html).

Comment: ok, I read all of that but I still don't understand how to get the actual information out of this.

In the ResponsHandler file there is a method "purchaseResponse" that should be called by the billing service and get the information I need. Now what do I do to get it from the method?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then. That's all the information I know about.